# What's the best way to call a function in Swift on a specific day?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to call a function the next time a user logs in after 00:01 of the first day of each month, but unsure how to do this. I was going to use a Timer but can't figure out how to know when it is the correct day.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you mean, you want to do something in your app, no matter of the state of the app, when the first day in month at 00:01 am did arrive? Or Server Side?

Comment: yes sorry I should of been more clear. I would like to call a function at 00:01 am on the first day of every month in my app

Answer (score 0):

That means you have to wake up the app at this time.

There is one way, that could send a silent push to your app. Well, this means as well that the user has to accept push messages. But a silent push will not arrive to them. After the push is received, u have about 30 seconds time to make your task ... but read about it because of side effects. 
read more https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

The other way is the approach for `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`
Well u can only add this, if you app is started.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I updated my question as i wasn't very clear. I want to call the function the next time the user logs in after 00:01 on the first day of each month

Comment: Than u have to check at first the Time. When u did this, u can perform your action for this special event and store an information, that u did this already. For example in the user defaults. for the next start u check this flag in the userDefaults.